# Mostrar fecha activa en un restrict range datepicker de jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un calendario dinámico en `jQuery`, en el cual deshabilito ciertos días, dependiendo del día actual. Y si es viernes, sábado o domingo, deshabilito toda la semana que venga a continuación.

El tema, es que necesito mostrar la fecha que queda activa para seleccionar en un `textbox`.

Mi codigo:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<!-- JS --> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<?php

    /*
    dias de la semana en numero
    0-> domingo
    6-> sabado
    */

    $dia = intval(date("w"));

    switch ($dia) {

        case 1:
            $dias = 7;
            $date = "";
        break;

        case 2:
            $dias = 6;
            $date = "";
        break;

        case 3:
            $dias = 5;
            $date = "";
        break;

        case 4:
            $dias = 4;
            $date = "";
        break;

        // viernes
        case 5:
            $dias = 10;
            $date = "";
        break;

        // sabado
        case 6:
            $dias = 10;
            $date = "";
        break;

        // domingo
        case 0:
            $dias = 10;
            $date = "";
        break;

    }
?>

<table border="1" align="center" class="sample">
    <tr style="height:25px">
        <th width="20%"  align="LEFT" >&nbsp;Fecha: &nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txt_fecha" name="txt_fecha" readonly="1" value="">
        </td>
        <input type="hidden" id="nro_dia" name="nro_dia" value="<?php echo $dias; ?>" />
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        //Array para dar formato en español
        $.datepicker.regional["es"] = {
            closeText: "Cerrar", 
            prevText: "Previo", 
            nextText: "Próximo",
            monthNames: ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio", "Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun", "Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dic"],
            monthStatus: "Ver otro mes",
            yearStatus: "Ver otro año",
            dayNames: ["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Dom","Lun","Mar","Mie","Jue","Vie","Sáb"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Do","Lu","Ma","Mi","Ju","Vi","Sa"],
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            firstDay: 0, 
            initStatus: "Selecciona la fecha",
            isRTL: false
        };

        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);

        //miDate: fecha de comienzo D=días | M=mes | Y=año
        //maxDate: fecha tope D=días | M=mes | Y=año

        $("#txt_fecha").focusin(function () {
            var dias = $("#nro_dia").val();
            var maxDate_d = dias+"D";
            //alert(date);
            $("#txt_fecha" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                firstDay: 1,
                minDate: maxDate_d
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

En el campo `txt_fecha` se debería mostrar la fecha activa que queda posterior a deshabilitar los días, ¿se entiende?

Comment: O sea, si es sábado, debería mostrarse como fecha activa el lunes?

Comment: Claro.. ejemplo, si fuese este sábado que ya paso, debería mostrarse activa la fecha del lunes 15.. en el textbox txt_fecha. GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo tienes que aplicar el método [setDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) después de iniciar el datePicker, con la misma variable que utilizaste para la propiedad minDate:

```
    $( "#txt_fecha" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: maxDate_d
    });
    $("#txt_fecha").datepicker("setDate", maxDate_d);
```

Comment: Lo había intentado, pero carga la fecha en el campo al momento de hacer click y no al cargar.. Lo hice con PHP, pondré el 'como' pronto para que lo vean =)

Comment: Claramente aparece solo al momento de hacer clic porque así está tu código, lo tienes atado al evento focusin. La pregunta no especifica en que momento deseas mostrarlo, así que asumí que el resto del código se mantiene igual.

Answer (score 0):

Lo intente de varias maneras, incluyendo como lo indica @Shaz (agradecido por tu respuesta..)

En la sección de PHP al inicio, en donde tengo el switch case, lo deje así;

```
<?php
/*
dias de la semana en numero
0-> domingo
6-> sabado
*/
$dia=intval(date('w'));
// echo "dia:".$dia."\n";
$today=date('Y-m-d');

switch($dia){
    case 1:
        $dias=7;
    break;

    case 2:
        $dias=6;
    break;

    case 3:
        $dias=5;
    break;

    case 4:
        $dias=4;
    break;
    // viernes
    case 5:
        $dias=10;
    break;
    // sabado
    case 6:
        $dias=10;
    break;
    // domingo
    case 0:
        $dias=10;
    break;
}
$date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$dias.' day',strtotime($today)));
?>
```

...y el HTML me quedo así;

```
<table border="1" align="center" class="sample">
<tr style="height:25px">
    <th width="20%"  align="LEFT" >&nbsp;Fecha: &nbsp;&nbsp; </th>
    <td><input type='text' id='txt_fecha' name='txt_fecha' readonly='1' onChange="BuscarActividades(this.value);" value='<?php echo $date; ?>'></td>
    <input type="hidden" id="nro_dia" name="nro_dia" value="<?php echo $dias; ?>" />
</tr>
</table>
```

De esta forma al cargar el sitio en el campo fecha, muestra la fecha activa posterior la regla de restricción que se requiere.

GRACIAS!!